# What does npm run do?

Tags: node.js, process

The command `npm run` will run the command which I set in the package.json, and I think it does not new a `child process` to run the command. What does npm do to run the command without new a `child process`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Npm run** has nothing to do with the node child process if that is what you are asking. Npm run is a command provided by npm CLI which allows to instantiate a shell and execute the command provided in the package.json file of your project.

Considering this is your package.json :

```
{
  "name": "my-awesome-package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "script" : { "test" : "mocha ./test/unit/mytest.js" }
}
```

Now if you execute `npm run test`, npm will simply go and check in package.json script section for 'test' key and execute that command in shell or cmd.exe based on your operating system.

If you have not installed mocha globally the command will show error in the console itself, OR if the file `mytest.js` does not exist the CLI will throw an error which is similar to just typing `mocha ./tests/unit/mytest.json`

This paragraph from the [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script) which is pretty self-explanatory.

> The actual shell your script is run within is platform dependent. By
>   default, on Unix-like systems it is the /bin/sh command, on Windows it
>   is the cmd.exe. The actual shell referred to by /bin/sh also depends
>   on the system. As of npm@5.1.0, you can customize the shell with the
>   script-shell configuration.

---

Update : As per the response in comment, if you want to execute CLI commands via. node without using `child_process` api you can  try `exec` or `execsync(cmd)` as a simple workround.This will simply execute your shell cmd and return to your code if no errors were found.

Comment: What I want to know is: can I run a command without child_process in nodejs just like the npm run do?

Comment: Well your question is very misleading

Comment: Indeed. This answers the original question.

Answer (score 4):

I want to add an answer since the accepted one is outdated for npm v8.

`run`, `rum` and `urn` are aliases for `run-script`.

What `npm run X` does is to run the command under the key `X` inside `scripts` object.

If the command to run isn't installed globally, it will search on `node_modules` because `npm` adds to the OS PATH `node_modules`.

So, an example:

```
`npm run test`
```

If in `package.json` we have:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest --runInBand",
```

The `npm` will try to execute the globally installed `jest` command. And if it's not globally, then it will search on `node_modules`.

Comment: The aliases didn't change in NPM 8 - `rum` and `urn` (which anyway are to catch typos, not intended for use), were added in v7. Also the second part of the answer is totally incorrect - NPM looks in `./node_modules/.bin` _first_, so that your package can use the local dependencies it declared not whatever else you had installed on your machine.