# How to create a React UI library where, when installed, let programmers launch it with a terminal command (npm script), similar to Storybook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm, next.js

I'm creating a UI project, similtar to Storybook. After npm install, run "npm run PROJECT_NAME -p 5000" to launch the UI on port 5000. I need guidance on this functionality. How can I research it? Thank you!

I attempted to create a .bin/script_file to expose the run command (similar to the Storybook command), but it proved unsuccessful.

Comment: do you know [what npm run does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49276903/5053002)?